# После установки UE5, эдитор выдает такую ошибку при создании c++ пректа

Tags: c++, unreal-engine, unreal-engine-5

[image: Ошибка, которая вылезает при создании C++ проект]

После установки UE5, эдитор выдает такую ошибку при создании c++ пректа, как исправит данную ошибку
кому нужно вот текст:
Running D:/UE_5.1/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat  -projectfiles -project="C:/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "....\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -projectfiles -project="C:/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
"dotnet" ?? ?? ???७??? ??? ???譥?
????????, ?ᯮ??塞?? ?ணࠬ??? ??? ?????? 䠩???.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: dotnet.core не установлен. Попробуйте установить Visual Studio 2019 и все пакеты, относящиеся к DotNet.